# Fluid layout of grid in xaml Winrt application

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I want to build a windows 8 app in C# & Xaml , which has the home screen something like fluid grid where one group follows the second group like the start screen of windows 8 screen. !http://postimg.org/image/4ygwladm9/

I have implemented many a times a screen where we can have sections starting a new column altogether but no where I found a fluid thing as mentioned above.

The usual code is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780633.aspx).

Please help me out if you have come across the same problem before.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer in this blog.

Hope next time you guys have same scenario you can refer to this.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/going_metro/archive/2012/07/15/grid-view-similar-to-people-app-s-contacts-page.aspx